# Solace integration with Kafka over TCPS failing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, solace

I am trying to connect Solace cloud broker with Kafka. I have a topic in Solace cloud. I want to subscribe into the Solace topic through the [pub-sub-plus source connector](https://github.com/SolaceProducts/pubsubplus-connector-kafka-source).

Here are my Source Connector Configuration:

```
{
    "name": "solaceSource",
    "config": {
        "name":"solaceSource",
        "kafka.topic":"solace-connector-test",
        "tasks.max":"1",
        "connector.class":"com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnector",
        "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "sol.host":"tcps://mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud:55555",
        "sol.username":"solace-cloud-client",
        "sol.password":"thesecretpassword",
        "sol.vpn_name":"solaceservice",
        "sol.topics": "sourcetest",
        "sol.ssl_trust_store":"/opt/external-cert/myTrustStore.jks",
        "sol.ssl_trust_store_password":"changeit",
        "sol.message_processor_class":"com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.msgprocessors.SolSampleSimpleMessageProcessor",
        "sol.dynamic_destination":"true",
        "errors.log.enable":"true"
    }
}
```

I have downloaded the PEM file from the given connection details and insert it into the myTrustStore.jks file.

I am getting the following error:
**Received Solace exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**

Error Log:

```
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,127] INFO Creating task solaceSource-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,128] INFO ConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
        name = solaceSource
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,128] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
        name = solaceSource
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,128] INFO TaskConfig values:
        task.class = class com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,128] INFO Instantiated task solaceSource-0 with version 2.0.2 of type com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,128] INFO StringConverterConfig values:
        converter.encoding = UTF8
        converter.type = key
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverterConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,129] INFO Set up the key converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter for task solaceSource-0 using the connector config (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,129] INFO Set up the value converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter for task solaceSource-0 using the connector config (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,129] INFO Set up the header converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter for task solaceSource-0 using the worker config (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,132] INFO Initializing: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain{} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,135] INFO ProducerConfig values:
        acks = all
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [broker:29092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = connector-producer-solaceSource-0
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
        max.request.size = 25728640
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 2147483647
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,177] INFO Kafka version: 5.4.1-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,177] INFO Kafka commitId: fd1e543386b47352 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,177] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1615613584176 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,257] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=compose-connect-group] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,260] INFO SolaceSourceConnectorConfig values:
        kafka.topic = solace-connector-test
        sol.authentication_scheme = AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_BASIC
        sol.calculate_message_expiration = false
        sol.channel_properties.compression_level = 0
        sol.channel_properties.connect_retries = 0
        sol.channel_properties.connect_timout_in_millis = 30000
        sol.channel_properties.keep_alive_interval_in_millis = 3000
        sol.channel_properties.keep_alive_limit = 10
        sol.channel_properties.read_timeout_in_millis = 10000
        sol.channel_properties.receive_buffer = 65536
        sol.channel_properties.reconnect_retries = 0
        sol.channel_properties.reconnect_retry_wait_in_millis = 3000
        sol.channel_properties.send_buffer = 65536
        sol.channel_properties.tcp_no_delay = true
        sol.channnel_properties.connect_retries_per_host = 0
        sol.client_name = default
        sol.generate_rcv_timestamps = false
        sol.generate_send_timestamps = false
        sol.generate_sender_id = false
        sol.generate_sequence_numbers = false
        sol.host = tcps://mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud:55555
        sol.ignore_duplicate_subscription_error = false
        sol.ignore_subscription_not_found_error = false
        sol.kafka_message_key = NONE
        sol.kerberos.krb5.conf =
        sol.kerberos.login.conf =
        sol.krb_service_name = solace
        sol.localhost = null
        sol.message_callback_on_reactor = false
        sol.message_processor_class = class com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.msgprocessors.SolSampleSimpleMessageProcessor
        sol.no_local = false
        sol.password = thesecretpassword
        sol.pub_multi_thread = true
        sol.pub_use_immediate_direct_pub = true
        sol.queue = null
        sol.reapply_subscriptions = true
        sol.ssl_cipher_suites =
        sol.ssl_connection_downgrade_to =
        sol.ssl_excluded_protocols =
        sol.ssl_key_store =
        sol.ssl_key_store_format = JKS
        sol.ssl_key_store_normalized_format = JKS
        sol.ssl_key_store_password =
        sol.ssl_private_key_alias =
        sol.ssl_private_key_password =
        sol.ssl_trust_store = /opt/external-cert/myTrustStore.jks
        sol.ssl_trust_store_format = JKS
        sol.ssl_trust_store_password = changeit
        sol.ssl_trusted_common_name_list =
        sol.ssl_validate_certicate_date = true
        sol.ssl_validate_certificate = true
        sol.sub_ack_window_size = 255
        sol.subscriber_dto_override = true
        sol.susbcriber_local_priority = 1
        sol.susbcriber_network_priority = 1
        sol.topics = sourcetest
        sol.username = solace-cloud-client
        sol.vpn_name = solaceservice
 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnectorConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,261] INFO ==================Initialize Connector properties (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceConnectorConfig)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,262] INFO =============Attempting to use SSL for PubSub+ connection (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,337] INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-solaceSource-0] Cluster ID: pg9lYRyXSXGikF0NIZpRqw (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2021-03-13 05:33:04,972] INFO Connecting to host 'orig=tcps://mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud:55555, scheme=tcps://, host=mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud, port=55555' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 2, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,022] INFO SSLEngine Supported Protocols: [SSLV3, TLSV1, TLSV1.1, TLSV1.2] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,023] INFO Application Specified Protocols: [SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,023] INFO Enabled Protocols: [SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,024] INFO The following specified cipher suites are not supported: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,024] INFO SSLEngine Supported Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,024] INFO Application Specified Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:05,025] INFO Enabled Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384] (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient)
[2021-03-13 05:33:24,259] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=solaceSource-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:24,259] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=solaceSource-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:26,054] INFO Connection attempt failed to host 'mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud' ConnectException com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException: (Client name: connect/1/#005b0001/lV4shEwB95   Local port: -1   Remote addr: mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud:55555) - Error communicating with the router. cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused ((Client name: connect/1/#005b0001/lV4shEwB95   Local port: -1   Remote addr: mr-12uy34hj345.messaging.solace.cloud:55555) - ) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,056] INFO Channel Closed (smfclient 2) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,065] INFO Received Solace exception java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused, with the following: [com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpChannel.executePostOnce(TcpChannel.java:263), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.ChannelOpStrategyClient.performOpen(ChannelOpStrategyClient.java:90), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.performOpenSingle(TcpClientChannel.java:416), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.access$800(TcpClientChannel.java:106), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel$ClientChannelConnect.call(TcpClientChannel.java:2390), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.open(TcpClientChannel.java:392), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPBasicSession.sniffRouter(JCSMPBasicSession.java:354), com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPBasicSession.connect(JCSMPBasicSession.java:1191), com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler.connectSession(SolSessionHandler.java:176), com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask.start(SolaceSourceTask.java:84), org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:208), org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177), org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227), java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511), java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]  (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,066] INFO ================ Failed to create JCSMPSession Session (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,066] INFO ================ Shutting down PubSub+ Source Connector (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,066] INFO Final Statistics summary:
 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_MSGS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_SOCKET_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_SOCKET_COMPRESSED_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_SOCKET_SSL_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_SENT_CONFIRMED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_MSGS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_MSGS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_DIRECT_MSGS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_DIRECT_BYTES_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_MSGS_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_SOCKET_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_SOCKET_COMPRESSED_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_SOCKET_SSL_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_RECVED_ACKED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_MSGS_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_MSGS_RECVED_ACKED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_MSGS_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_MSGS_RECVED_ACKED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_DIRECT_MSGS_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_DIRECT_BYTES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_DISCARDED_OUTOFORDER: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_DISCARDED_DUPLICATES: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  TOTAL_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS: 1 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_MSGS_RESENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_PERSISTENT_BYTES_RESENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_MSGS_RESENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_NONPERSISTENT_BYTES_RESENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_RESENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_BYTES_RESENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  ROUTER_DISCARD_NOTIFICATIONS: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  SMF_DISCARDS_UNKNOWN_ELEMENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  RELIABLE_MSGS_DISCARDED_NO_MATCHING_FLOW: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  PUBLISHER_WINDOW_CLOSED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  SUBSCRIBER_FLOW_WINDOW_CLOSED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  MESSAGES_DISCARDED_INTERNAL: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  SUBSCRIBER_CONGESTED_EVENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  CACHE_REQUESTS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  CACHE_REQUESTS_FULFILLED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,067] INFO  CACHED_MESSAGES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  CACHE_FULFILL_REPLIES_DISCARDED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  REQUESTS_SENT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  REQUESTS_TIMED_OUT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  RESPONSES_RECVED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  DISCARDED_RESPONSES: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  MESSAGES_REJECTED_BY_APPLIANCE: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  TOTAL_OK_RESPONSE_CALLBACKS: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  TOTAL_ERROR_RESPONSE_CALLBACKS: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  TOTAL_ACK_TIMEOUT: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO  TOTAL_SEND_METHOD_CALLED: 0 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO
 (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolSessionHandler)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,068] INFO Channel Closed (smfclient 2) (com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,075] INFO PubSub+ Source Connector stopped (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,075] INFO ================ JCSMPSession Connected (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,075] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=solaceSource-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,104] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=solaceSource-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,107] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=solaceSource-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTopicListener.init(SolaceSourceTopicListener.java:60)
        at com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask.start(SolaceSourceTask.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:208)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,108] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=solaceSource-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,108] INFO ================ Shutting down PubSub+ Source Connector (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
[2021-03-13 05:33:29,108] INFO PubSub+ Source Connector stopped (com.solace.connector.kafka.connect.source.SolaceSourceTask)
```

---

> Any workarounds ?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question could be found here! https://solace.community/discussion/646/solace-integration-with-kafka-over-tcps-failing